# Can I access a class that has a collection from that collection?

Tags: c#, collections

I have a class A that has a collection of class B. Is it possible to access class A from instances of class B in that collection?

```
Class A
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    List<B> collection = new List<b>();
    public void Add(B b)
    {
        collection.Add(b);
    }
}

Class B
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
    b.Num = 5;

    A a = new A();
    a.Something = "Hello";
    a.Add(b);
}
```

Is there any way to access string a.Something from object b?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B would need to contain reference to its container A. So sth like:

```
Class B
{
    public int Num { get; set; }
    public A Container { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Add() method in A:

```
public void Add(B b)
{
        collection.Add(b);
        b.Container = this;
}
```

That's assuming B can only be added to single instance of A. Otherwise you need to use a collection (eg. List) and update it accordingly on Add/Remove.

Answer (score 0):

With the following changes, it is possible; but be warned that it does not make sense at all.

```
Class A
{
    public string Something { get; set; }
    List<B> collection = new List<b>();
    public void Add(B b)
    {
        b.Master = this;
        collection.Add(b);        
    }
}

Class B
{
    public A Master {get; set;}
    public int Num { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
    b.Num = 5;

    A a = new A();
    a.Something = "Hello";
    a.Add(b);
    Console.Writeline(b.Master.Something);
}
```

Comment: I also first though about this solution, but it's quite flawed. Consider creating two `A` objects and adding one `B` object to each of them. In such case `B` would hold a reference only to the last added. So you either need to have `List<A> Masters` or reconsider the design of the app and access `Something` from `A`. I'm not even touching removing of `B` scenario

Answer (score -1):

`Is there any way to access string a.Something from object b?`

NO. You CAN'T.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but despite having their own problems as described, there are solutions to this question.